# Keyboard shortcut for GPS data capture in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gps, data-capture

I would like to setup keyboard shortcuts for GPS data capture with QGIS.

Using GPS Information dialog box, I could use Mouse-Left-Click to "Add feature" and "Add track point", but I would like to assign keyboard shortcuts for them so that I can use a programmable Mouse.

Settings --> Configure Shortcuts lists only few commands

Is there a way I can call the API behind that and assign to a shortcut key?

Comment: Which OS are you using? There are both built-in and third-party applications that can help with this, but depends on which system you're using.

Comment: @Simbamangu Windows 7 and I intend to use CM Storm Sentinel Advance II mouse which comes with its own program to assign shortcuts [link](http://www.cmstorm.com/en/products/peripherals/sentineladvanceII/)

Answer (score 1):

The following code will allow you to access the GPS action:

```
GPSdock = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, "GPSInformation")
button = GPSdock.findChild(QPushButton, "mBtnCloseFeature")
button.click()
```

You can wrap this logic in a plugin by using the QGIS Plugin Builder plugin from inside QGIS to get you a template for the plugin.  Example coming later..